# Order confirmation page is with no information?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using this code to redirect a payment module on order confirmation.

```
Tools::redirect(__PS_BASE_URI__.'order-confirmation.php?key='.$key1.'&id_cart='.$cart->id.'&id_module='.$this->module->id.'&id_order='.$this->module->currentOrder);
```

but i am getting a page with this link `/prestashop/en/order-confirmation?key=67db4962c0c85b3241be97dcbedd869d&id_cart=301&id_module=82&id_order=265`
that is with no information of order confirming at all.Can anybody help me with this to fix ?
Can anybody help me to set a template after order confirmation? 
I am also attaching a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: which payment method are you using? how you structured order-confirmation.tpl?

Comment: Hi Matteo,  I havent made any .tpl file for this i just redirect my payment to order-confirmation controller which is actually a core controller.. Is any way througj which i will set my template  after redirecting to any controller..I tried making a new contrroller which will set template but it doesnt work for me..I am not able to implement that stuff..N thanks for your reply.. Hopefully  u will come with some solutions for me.. And i am making a custom payment module

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a payment module you need to register two hooks:

1. `displayPayment`

   This hook displays your payment option's HTML at payment selection page.
2. `displayPaymentReturn`

   This hook displays your confirmation page HTML after you validate an order and redirect it to order-confirmation controller.

Comment: public function hookDisplayPayment($params)
 {
  $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/newgenpaymentgiropay.css', 'all');
  $controller = $this->getHookController('displayPayment');
  return $controller->run($params);
 }

Comment: public function hookDisplayPaymentReturn($params)
 {
  $controller = $this->getHookController('displayPaymentReturn');
  return $controller->run($params);
 }

Comment: diplay payment is working but i am not able to redirect my payment in display payment return controller

Comment: is anything else i have to mention to get redirected from core order-confirmation controller to displayPaymentReturn

Comment: It looks like hook controller for displayPaymentReturn is not outputting its template. Or could be throwing silent errors, do you have dev mode enabled?